# Webservice PHP doesn't receive base64 large image

Tags: c#, php, base64

I have an issue that i can't explain

I have a C# program which send image ( screenshot whole web page of some url ) encoding to base64

```
    static string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }

    // image is typeof Bitmap
    string myImageData = ImageToBase64(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {

                byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://production/ws/imageBuilder", new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    { "myImageData", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.myImageData) }
                    { "Url_", url.Authority },
                    { "token", ImageHash }
                });

                Debug.WriteLine("Server Said: " + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response));

                byte[] response2 = client.UploadValues("http://localhost/ws/imageBuilder", new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    { "myImageData", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.myImageData) }
                    { "Url_", url.Authority },
                    { "token", ImageHash }
                });

                Debug.WriteLine("Server Said: " + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response2));
            } 
            catch(Exception e) {Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);}
        }
```

On PHP side I have just for testing

```
        echo "length before decode ".strlen($_POST['myImageData']);
        $imageData = base64_decode(urldecode($_POST['myImageData']));
        echo "length after decode ".strlen($imageData);
```

Which is returning with large image ( exemple 1280 x 10 000 )

```
[4908] Server Said: length before decode 0   length after decode 0 
[4908] Server Said: length before decode 1333258   length after decode 925151
```

So on my local WAMP server ( on Windows 7 ) I receive the image but in production ( on Linux ) i receive nothing.

But with "small" image for exemple dimension "1280 x 1024" it's okay, my variable `$_POST['myImageData']` is not empty on production, it works fine.

```
[4908] Server Said: length before decode 66292 length after decode 46210 
[4908] Server Said: length before decode 66292 length after decode 46210
```

**UPDATE :** Images are small JPG ( between 200ko and 1.5mo ).

on my php.in in production I have

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 18M
```

My Apache in production is **mod_proxy**

Comment: Are you hitting an upload limit? If you send the image as `multipart/form-data` you might be better luck. Then the webserver will give you an error message as file-input instead of the file. Another thing to note is that base64 encoding inflates your data by about 33%.

Comment: My post_max_size is enough. It's just a JPEG image, between 200ko et 1.5 mo :/ I'll try multipart/form-data

Answer (score 0):

If I had to venture a guess I would say check your "post_max_size" parameter in your php.ini. It is probably set lower on the linux server than the WAMP server.

Comment: My post_max_size is enough. It's just a JPEG image, approximately 1mo :/